# Reference a non primary key in another table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a two columns should references two columns in another table. And those two columns are not primary key. I think I can't use foreign key, because it can only references primary keys.

Answer (score 8):

Postgres supports foreign keys to unique indexes (a primary key is a special case of a unique key). From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html)

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a foreign key.  It seems like your model is not normalized.  Review your data model and try to get it to third normal form.

If those two columns form a natural (and unique) key, then add a unique key containing those two rules.  Then reference the primary key of the other table.   Remove the columns from the table that needs to reference the columns and use a join when you need the columns

In the above solution, the primary key is a surrogate key for your two columns.  I usually use a surrogate key for table where the natural key consists of two or more fields.  If any part of the natural key could change, then a surrogate is usually preferred.

If the two columns you want to reference are not unique in second table, then you could move them to a third table where they are unique.  Then use a foreign key reference from both tables to the new table.